# Failed to send message using MQ

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq

On my server side I deployed RabbitMq message middleware using docker and it works perfectly. But I combine it with asp.net core, it can't send the message successfully.

package:https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client/

I goole some answers:

> RabbitMQ adopts the message response mechanism, that is, after the
> consumer receives a message, it needs to send a response, and then
> RabbitMQ will delete the message from the queue. If the consumer has
> an exception during the consumption process, the connection is
> disconnected and no response is sent. Then RabbitMQ will redeliver the
> message

So I modified my code

```
//message received event
consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
{
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);

    Console.WriteLine($"Received the news： {message}");

    Console.WriteLine($"received the message[{ea.DeliveryTag}] delay 10s to send receipt");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    //Confirm that the message has been consumed
    channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
    Console.WriteLine($"Receipt sent[{ea.DeliveryTag}]");
};
```

Still failed to send and no response, please help me, thank you!

Comment: Is the Publisher code working fine? Are you getting anything in the `message` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a demo of sending a message, you may refer to it, it may be helpful.

Controller:

```
    [Route("test")]
    public void Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.VirtualHost = "/";
            factory.HostName = "localhost";
            factory.Port = 5672;
            factory.UserName = "guest";//Default username guest
            factory.Password = "guest";//Default password guest
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "test",
                                     durable: false,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);

                string message = "Hello World!";
                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                     routingKey: "test",
                                     basicProperties: null,
                                     body: body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("RabbitMQ connection error :{0}\n", ex.ToString()));
        }

    }
```

For the sake of convenience, I did not configure the connection information of rabbitmq here. I wrote it directly into the method, you can do it yourself.

Resullt:

[image]

[image]